# How to achieve the equivalent of "short-circuit evaluation" in T-sql

Tags: sql-server, short-circuiting

I have this select scenario:

I would like to return **exact matches first**, then only check for partial matches progressively, using a simple T-sql query.

```
select * from accounts where 
   mobile = @mobile or  
   mobile like @mobile +'%' or 
   mobile like '%'+@mobile or 
   mobile like '%'+@mobile +'%'
```

I understand that `T-sql` performs **All-At-Once Operations**.

How best can this be achieved?

Comment: SQL Server does not support "short-circuit" bool evaluation and there's no option to "turn it on" either....

Comment: @marc_s that's why i'm asking, how can we achieve the *equivalent* of a short-circuited where clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could evaluate in a CASE and provide a ranking value:

```
select
  mobile,
  case 
    when mobile = @mobile             then 1  
    when mobile like @mobile +'%'     then 2 
    when mobile like '%'+@mobile      then 3 
    when mobile like '%'+@mobile +'%' then 4
  end as [Rank]
from accounts where 
   mobile = @mobile or  
   mobile like @mobile +'%' or 
   mobile like '%'+@mobile or 
   mobile like '%'+@mobile +'%'
order by [Rank]
```

Comment: This solution does not produce duplicate like the **union** solution. Thanks

Comment: It also does not traverse the source table a bunch of times. Add an outer filter query and it does the same I think.

Comment: I get what you're doing and I agree it's correct and a preferred solution from a set-based perspective, but it's not really short-circuiting, since it will most likely go over the entire table, at least once.

Comment: Yep, also in this case because of the wildcard patterns used even if the column is indexed a full table scan is required for two of the WHERE clauses, avoiding this by limiting the queries should be the absolute priority.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is to split your query into multiple queries. I'm not saying this gives the best performance, but:

```
select * from accounts
where mobile = @mobile

union

select * from accounts
where like @mobile +'%'
    and not exists (select 1 from accounts where mobile = @mobile)

union

select * from accounts
where mobile like '%'+@mobile
    and not exists (select 1 from accounts where like @mobile +'%')

union

select * from accounts
where mobile like '%'+@mobile +'%'
    and not exists (select 1 from accounts where like '%'+@mobile)
```

Something else that you can do, which is more "programatic" is to use `@@ROWCOUNT`, which should give better performance since it simulates short-circuiting.

```
select * from accounts
where mobile = @mobile

if @@rowcount = 0
    select * from accounts
    where like @mobile +'%'

if @@rowcount = 0
    select * from accounts
    where mobile like '%'+@mobile

if @@rowcount = 0
    select * from accounts
    where mobile like '%'+@mobile +'%'
```

Comment: and this is because of "All-At-Once Operations"?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu Well, you need to understand first that SQL is a declarative language, you don't tell it how to do things, you just tell it how you want the result and it will get it for you. Let me see if I can find a blog post that explains this in more detail. What I have done is somewhat of a "short-circuit", where actually I broke it down into individual queries. The first will run on its own, then the 2nd, then the 3rd and 4th, but starting from the 2nd query they have an additional condition based on IF the previous query returned any results.

Comment: The variation with the @@rowcount is brilliant. Thanks